# Bootstrap 3 div with span issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this div that holds any span added to the list

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <label>Batch Ref List</label>
    </div>
    <div id="div_list" class="col-md-5">
    </div>
</div>
```

And a button somewhere else to just add a span into the div, but when I am starting the span, it just goes on and doesnt create a new line.

span html is

```
<button type="button" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true" style="border:none; background-color:transparent;" onclick="remove_element(this);">×</button>
```

It looks something like this.

[image]

What i need for it to do is once it reach the end, it will automatically 'go down' or create a new line

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: can you recreate the issue in a plunker/fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width of the spans depends on the font size, so you can't create a new line when it reach the end, but you can use the css float property.

"float: left;" on your spans, and a "clear: both;" on the next element to adjust the height of your container.